# Unable to install intl: ^0.16.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am working on the Flutter APP. In the pubspec.yaml file I have copied the code for **intl**.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    intl: ^0.16.1
```

And save the page it shows me the error as shown below. please suggest.

```
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

I have follow the step as shown in the official website. https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

**Edit 1**

```
subtitle:Text(
  DateFormat.yMMMD().format(lstTrack[index].dt),
),
```

It shows me error

```
Error: Method not found: 'DateFormat.yMMMD'.
                          DateFormat.yMMMD().format(lstTrack[index].dt),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it like this. You have wrong indentation.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

Comment: The error has gone but now I have a new error. I have edited my question please have a look. And thank you in advance.

Comment: For your new problem do it like this;     subtitle: Text("${DateFormat.yMMMD().format(lstTrack[index].dt)}"),